# How to append new components after init of the Vue [VueJS]

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to append a new element on the DOM and make that element be used by VueJS ?

For example in this https://jsfiddle.net/a0hnps42/1/ the element `<lel>after</lel>` is not transformed into `<div class='lel'>lele</div>` as `<lel>before</lel>` did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use scoped [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots) to dynamically add new components:

```
<ul>
  <slot name="item"
    v-for="item in items"
    :text="item.text">
    <!-- fallback content here -->
  </slot>
</ul>
```

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/v2.1.0